# Draw bars in bar chart next to each other instead of vertically stacked

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I've been stuck for a week with a R script
I'm trying to make a graph and I can't get separate bars for my data they are superimposed on each other

I have an excel file containing 3 columns,
column1: the values of X represented as a sequence (T, U, K, L ....etc)
Column2: the values of a first batch of data in percentage corresponding to the Y axis
Column3: the values of a second batch of data in percentage corresponding to the Y axis

I want to draw a figure with sticks where each lot has a color and the sticks of each lot are side by side

example of excel table:

```
COG_category      involved_percent      BO4_percent
NC                  22.01                   20.47
S                   17.25                   18.95
T                   14.96                   7.83
Y                   8.8                     7.17

data <- structure(list(COG_category = c("NC", "S", "T", "Y"), involved_percent = c(22.01, 
17.25, 14.96, 8.8), BO4_percent = c(20.47, 18.95, 7.83, 7.17)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

My R script:

```
#read file
data<- read.csv2("COGs_graph.csv")
data
library(ggplot2)
 
#Plot the data
ggplot(data, aes(x = COG_category, y = involved_percent, fill = "involved_percent")) +
 geom_col(width = 0.5, position = "dodge") +
 geom_col(aes(x = COG_category, y = BO4_percent, fill = "BO4_percent"), width = 0.5, position = "dodge") +
 scale_fill_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("Candidate_percent" = "blue", "BO4_percent" = "red")) +
 xlab("Value of X") + ylab("Percentage") +
 ggtitle("Figure title") +
 theme(legend. position = "bottom")
```

an image of the result I'am obtaining:
[image]

I want to perform an image like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works. Bring your data in long format (always a good idea, when working with ggplot), remove the second geom_col in ggplot, adapt the names:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-COG_category) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = COG_category, y = value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.5, position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("involved_percent" = "blue", "BO4_percent" = "red")) + 
  xlab("Value of X") + ylab("Percentage") + 
  ggtitle("Figure title") + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]